# Include 3rd party hosted javascript in react/node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am wanting to include a 3rd party javascript file in my node.js / react.js app. I understand that I can http require this file. So lets say I needed to include http://example.com/remotejs.js in my react / node app. What would be the best way to do this?

I previously thought of creating an npm module for this, however I thought there must be an easier way. Please see my code below:

```
var http = require('http')
  , vm = require('vm')
  , concat = require('concat-stream')
  , async = require('async');

function http_require(url, callback) {
  http.get(url, function(res) {
    // console.log('fetching: ' + url)
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.pipe(concat({encoding: 'string'}, function(data) {
      callback(null, vm.runInThisContext(data));
    }));
  })
}

urls = [
  'http://example.com/remote.js',
];

async.map(urls, http_require, function(err, results) {
  console.log(results);
  // `results` is an array of values returned by `runInThisContext`
  // the rest of your program logic
});
```

Comment: Download the file and put it onto your server, then require?

Comment: As specified, I cannot do this as the JS is dynamically generated.